Access to Group Policy is denied to Everyone at the top level of the domain
An access control entry was created that denies access to Everyone at top level of the domain.
How can this be reset?
Cannot open GPO Management, cannot open AD Users & Computers.


Deny always trumps any Allows, and Everyone means, well Everyone, including domain admins and the domain administrator. I think the only way to correct this would be restoring the domain controllers from a backup or manually editing the NTDS.DIT file, which would be an impressive feat to do correctly.
